# SQL query to get 5 year interval

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQL table that looks like this.
[my SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVrvV.png)

This is my solution for querying sales of each product and grouping them by year

```
SELECT  product_name, year, MAX(no_of_sale)
FROM petroleum_report
GROUP BY year, product_name;
```

which returns me this.(there is more)

```
Product                   Year          Max 
Aviation Turbine Fuel     2000         63131
Diesel                    2000        326060
Furnace Oil               2000         20934
Kerosene                  2000         316381
LPG in MT                 2000         40102
Light Diesel Oil          2000         3416
Mineral Turpentine Oil    2000         132
Petrol                    2000         59245
Aviation Turbine Fuel     2001         47453
Diesel                    2001         286233
Furnace Oil               2001         18255
Kerosene                  2001         386592
LPG in MT                 2001         48757
Light Diesel Oil          2001         2413
Mineral Turpentine Oil    2001         120
```

Now, how do I query the sale of each Petroleum Product for 5 years interval? How Do I group by year interval? I want to output something like this.

```
Product     Year            Max 
Petrol      2010-2014       283567  
Petrol      2005-2009       162275  
Petrol      2000-2004       75989   
Diesel      2010-2014       901393  
Diesel      2005-2009       612505  
Diesel      2000-2004       326060  
Kerosene    2010-2014       49495   
Kerosene    2005-2009       226637  
Kerosene    2000-2004       386592
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt this SQL to your situation:
[as tested using your data sample here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/92b0e4/3/0).
You need to convert each year number in your data to a corresponding 5-year "bucket" (YearRange) which is what the FLOOR function is doing.

```
SELECT Product_Name AS Product, 
CAST(FLOOR(YearNum / 5) * 5 as CHAR) || '-' || 
     CAST((FLOOR(YearNum / 5) * 5) + 4 AS CHAR) AS YearRange, 
MAX(Max_Sales) AS Max
FROM stats
GROUP BY Product_Name, YearRange
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't understand why you are using `MAX()`.  `SUM()` seems more appropriate.  For the answer for your question:

```
select product_name, min(year), max(year), sum(no_of_sale)
from petroleum_report
group by product_name, floor( year / 5 );
```